# Are static URL paths valid after parameters in labstack/echo

Tags: go, go-echo

I’m chasing an odd pattern matching issue in **labstack/echo** and would like your thoughts.

Would the route

`/first/:parameter/second`

match the url
`http://hostname/first or http://hostname/first/`       ?

What about
`/first/:parameter1/second/:parameter2/:parameter3/third/`       ?

To my eye, they should *not* match the simple urls, but they appear to be. Is that desired behavior? Has anyone followed a parameter with a static in the url pattern?

Comment: No idea about echo, but for this cases dynamic/static I use https://violetear.org/, in where you could match a mix of both

Answer (score -1):

In Echo your routes need to be in an order to not match. See the Routing Guide here and look for Path Matching Order

https://echo.labstack.com/guide/routing

Switch around your routes so your `/first/:parameter/second` doesn't match `/first/:parameter1/second/:parameter2/:parameter3/third/`

Comment: do you mean the order of route declaration matters ? That doesn't seem to be the case, indicated by " Routes can be written in any order." stated on the referenced URL